# How do I use the addGeoJSON() feature in R for Leaflet?

Tags: r, leaflet, geojson

Could someone please explain how the addGeoJSON() feature works in R, I cannot make sense of the documentation.

?addGeoJSON => (map, geojson, layerId = NULL)

What is geojson and layerId?

I was able to import my GeoJSON using GDAL:
a1 <- readOGR(dsn = "myData.geojson", layer = "OGRGeoJSON")

How can I access the columns to plot x, y with leaflet addGeoJSON() ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first argument to `addGeoJSON` is the leaflet object, created from a call to `leaflet()`. e.g.,

```
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/glynnbird/usstatesgeojson/master/california.geojson"
geojson <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url)
library("leaflet")
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(lng = -98.583, lat = 39.833, zoom = 3) %>% 
  addGeoJSON(geojson)
```

[image]

You can just replace your geojson read in via `readOGR` with the `geojson` object I created

With `readOGR()`

```
library("leaflet")
library("rgdal")

url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/glynnbird/usstatesgeojson/master/california.geojson"
res <- readOGR(dsn = url, layer = "OGRGeoJSON")
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(lng = -98.583, lat = 39.833, zoom = 3) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = res)
```

You should replace `addPolygons(data = res)` with `addPolygons(data = res, lng = "feature.properties.long", lat = "feature.properties.lat")`

Should work for your example above. Both likely give back a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` class, which you need to pass to the `data` parameter either in `leaflet()` or `addPolygons()`.

Okay, if you're reading a geojson file from disk, with points, then e.g.,

```
geojson <- '{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features" :
  [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [ -123, 49 ]
      }, 
      "properties": {
        "a_property": "foo", 
        "some_object": {
          "a_property": 1, 
          "another_property": 2 
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}'
writeLines(geojson, "file.geojson")
res <- readOGR(dsn = "file.geojson", layer = "OGRGeoJSON")
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(lng = -123, lat = 49, zoom = 6) %>% 
  addMarkers(data = res)
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Scott,
If I add my own GeoJSON file nothing happens. As a data frame the columns I need are lat / long and as geojson object they are feature.properties.lat & long.

Any idea how I can add these points to my leaflet map via R?

Thank you

Comment: I'll edit the answer above to use `readOGR()`, just a sec, refresh page

Comment: Still not working, I'm looking for points, addMarkers not working either. Any idea how I can add points with AddGeoJSON() ?

Comment: I don't think you want `addGeoJSON()` - that's only if you have geojson data to pass in. `readOGR` should convert the geojson you read in to a spatial class object. What do you get when you do `class(a1)`

Comment: It is a SpatialPointsDataFrame, converted from the .GeoJSON format it was originally. I am able to load the GeoJSON file in my browser via HTML with Javascript + Leaflet but no luck yet displaying points with R + Leaflet

Comment: Dear @sckott, thank you for the great example! Is it feasible to extend your example with the addGeoJSON() function, to add multiple polygons? I tried with the [following geojson file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openseattle/seattle-boundaries/master/data/zip-codes.geojson) (Seattle zipcodes) but could not make it... Best regards

Comment: @sckott, I created a [dedicated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37933084/how-to-display-multiple-polygons-at-once-using-leaflet-addgeojson-function) - thank you in advance for your views on this issue!

Comment: answered over there