# How to display multiple polygons at once using leaflet addGeoJSON() function?

Tags: r, leaflet, polygon

I am trying to display several zipcodes (thus polygons...) on a `leaflet` map. Data is available as a `geojson` file [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openseattle/seattle-boundaries/master/data/zip-codes.geojson). I chose as an example some zip codes from Seattle.

I tried the following (reproducible example):

```
library(jsonlite) 
library(leaflet)  
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openseattle/seattle-boundaries/master/data/zip-codes.geojson"
geojson <- fromJSON(url) 
map <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addGeoJSON(geojson)
map
```

I could not figure out how to properly set `addGeoJSON` parameters, and calling map only displays the `leaflet() %>% addTiles()` part...

Documentation is too light for the non json advanced user that I am:

> geojson:  a GeoJSON list, or character vector of length 1

How should I proceed? Thank you very much in advance for your views on this issue

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just needed to not parse the geojson to a data.frame, `fromJSON(url, FALSE)`

```
library(jsonlite) 
library(leaflet)  
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openseattle/seattle-boundaries/master/data/zip-codes.geojson"
geojson <- fromJSON(url, simplifyVector = FALSE) 
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addGeoJSON(geojson) %>% 
  setView(lng = -122.2, lat = 47.6, zoom = 10)
```

[image]

`addGeoJSON()` will also accept a string, e.g.

```
geojson_str <- paste0(readLines(url), collapse = "")
```

then pass that to `addGeoJSON`